# Change a column in pandas dataframe with loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I have a dataframe "df" and I would like to change the value of a column if its values are lower compared to the ones in another column, so I have:

```
              A      B       C     
2017-01-01   10     200     24
2017-01-02   20     300     28
2017-01-03   30     400     29
2017-01-04   40     500     512
2017-01-05   50     600     680
2017-01-06   60     700     999
   ...       ..      ..     ..
2017-01-31   100    1200    1400
```

My goal is this: each time an element of B is higher than the element of C (on the same row), B will be divided by an integer until the value in B is lower than the one in C.

I tried to use a while loop:

```
while df['C']<df['B']:
    for i in range (0,len(df)-1):
        for k in range(0,10000):
            df[i]['B']=df[i]['B']/k
```

This does not work, and I get the following error message:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this ? Thank you very much

Comment: A lots of issues here in your code, don't know where to start. Are you searching to learn something or just have a solution and get rid of your problem?

Comment: This is actually a real problem I need to get rid of, hope it's not too much work for anyone though

Comment: Then I would recommend you to describe more in plain English your subsequent divisions "by an integer", as your code is not helping by dividing by zero and you're just gonna traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following applies the function f to every row in the df. The divisor starts at 2 and increments while row['B'] > row['C'].

```
def f(row):
    divisor = 2
    while row['B'] > row['C']:
        row['B'] = row['B'] / divisor
        divisor += 1
    return row

df.apply(f, axis=1)

print(df)
     B    C
0    8   24
1   12   28
2   16   29
3  500  512
4  600  680
5  700  999
```

Comment: Thank you very much